# Filtering out nested objects in JPA query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm struggling to filter on a third level nested object within my JPA repository query.

I have the following object, in which I want to receive all the proms which are part of the journey with id = 5 AND only the promMeasurement objects from the user with id = 12.

```
proms: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "test",
    journeys: [
      {
        id: 5
      },
      {
        id: 6
      },
    ]
    promMeasurements: [
      {
        id: 101,
        value: 6,
        user: {
          id: 12
        }
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        value: 2,
        user: {
          id: 13
        }
      },
      {
        id: 103,
        value: 8,
        user: {
          id: 14
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test 2",
    journeys: [
      {
        id: 5
      },
      {
        id: 6
      },
    ]
    promMeasurements: [
      {
        id: 223,
        value: 1,
        user: {
          id: 12
        }
      },
      {
        id: 224,
        value: 5,
        user: {
          id: 13
        }
      },
      {
        id: 225,
        value: 3,
        user: {
          id: 14
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "test 3",
    journeys: [
      {
        id: 7
      }
    ]
    promMeasurements: [
      {
        id: 223,
        value: 1,
        user: {
          id: 26
        }
      },
      {
        id: 224,
        value: 5,
        user: {
          id: 33
        }
      },
      {
        id: 225,
        value: 3,
        user: {
          id: 4
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

So the outcome of this all would be to have the following object in the end:

```
proms: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "test",
    journeys: [
      {
        id: 5
      }
    ]
    promMeasurements: [
      {
        id: 101,
        value: 6,
        user: {
          id: 12
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test 2",
    journeys: [
      {
        id: 5
      }
    ]
    promMeasurements: [
      {
        id: 223,
        value: 1,
        user: {
          id: 12
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Right now, I'm already able to do the filtering part on journeys by using this query:

```
List<Prom> findAllByJourneysId(Long id);
```

But filtering the promMeasurements didn't yet succeed.
A few examples of things I've tried. But those don't work as they just return the same result as the query above.

```
List<Prom> findAllByJourneysIdAndPromMeasurements_Patient_Id(Long journeyId, Long patientId);
List<Prom> findAllByJourneysIdAndPromMeasurementsPatientId(Long journeyId, Long patientId);
```

Query log of the last function:

```
[DEBUG] 2020-08-06 10:57:56.028 [qtp1976725830-44] SQL - select prom0_.id as id1_38_, prom0_.createdAt as createdA2_38_, prom0_.updatedAt as updatedA3_38_, prom0_.name as name4_38_, prom0_.threshold as threshol5_38_ from prom prom0_ left outer join prom_journey journeys1_ on prom0_.id=journeys1_.prom_id left outer join journey journey2_ on journeys1_.journey_id=journey2_.id left outer join prommeasurement prommeasur3_ on prom0_.id=prommeasur3_.prom_id left outer join user user4_ on prommeasur3_.patient_id=user4_.id left outer join user_address user4_1_ on user4_.id=user4_1_.user_id where journey2_.id=? and user4_.id=?
```

When I manually execute this function, I get the following result.
As you can see, each 'prom' is shown two times, which is already not correct.

[image: query-result]

Someone that can help me with this?

**Entities:**

```
public class Prom extends DateAudit {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "prom_journey", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "prom_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "journey_id"))
  @JsonBackReference(value = "prom-journeys")
  private Set<Journey> journeys = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prom")
  @JsonManagedReference(value = "prom-prom-measurements")
  private List<PromMeasurement> promMeasurements;
}

public class PromMeasurement extends DateAudit {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })    
  @JsonBackReference(value = "prom-prom-measurements")
  private Prom prom;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
  @JsonBackReference(value = "patient-prom-measurements")
  private User patient;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
  @JsonBackReference(value = "journey-prom-measurements")
  private Journey journey;

  private Integer value;
}

public class User extends DateAudit {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}

public class Journey extends DateAudit {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Any exception you got?

Comment: Nope, just receiving the same result as with the query findAllByJourneysId.

Comment: Ok, can you add the entity definitions

Comment: I added them :)

Comment: Can you add executed query logs ?

Comment: `WHERE journey2_.id = ? AND user4_.id = ?` query executed properly check your data in database and run same query value in database to check it's working or not

Comment: Updated my question with the result of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with the @Query annotation

```
@Query(value = "SELECT distinct p FROM Prom p JOIN FETCH p.journeys pj JOIN FETCH p.promMeasurements pp JOIN FETCH pp.patient ppp WHERE pj.id = :journeyId AND ppp.id = :patientId")
```

List findDistinctByJourneysIdAndPromMeasurementsPatientId(Long journeyId, Long patientId);

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of spring-boot you are using but from version 2.x the underscores and not necessary.

Possibly the problem comes with the fact that you are mixing both underscores:

```
PromMeasurements_Patient_Id
```

and without underscores parts of the query:

```
findAllByJourneysId
```

Try to stay consistent in your query language usage.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that part, but unfortunately leaving out the underscores doesn't do the trick. Also, when I hover over the method it says the following: "Expected parameter types: Journey, PromMeasurement"